# Does Tarjan's SCC algorithm give a topological sort of the SCC?

Tags: algorithm, graph, topological-sort, tarjans-algorithm

I've been studying SCC and algorithms about them, and I've seen that people almost always mention that Kosaraju's algorithm finds the SCC and also gives them ordered in a (reversed) topological sort.

My question is: doesn't Tarjan's algorithm also find a (reversed) topological sort? I've found that it isn't mentioned (at least from where I've read, except wikipedia).

I've been thinking about it and make perfect sense. When tarjans_dfs is called on some node u, all SCCs that are reachable from u will be found before u's SCC. Am I wrong?

Wikipedia says it actually does find it:

> "While there is nothing special about the order of the nodes within
>   each strongly connected component, one useful property of the
>   algorithm is that no strongly connected component will be identified
>   before any of its successors. Therefore, the order in which the
>   strongly connected components are identified constitutes a reverse
>   topological sort of the DAG formed by the strongly connected
>   components."

Is it my idea, or is it much more known that Kosaraju's algorithm finds the topological order than the fact that Tarjan's also does it?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Are you asking whether this is true? (it is) Or are you asking whether more people know about Kosaraju producing reverse sorted components vs Tarjan? I mean, unless someone has done a poll, how are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: haha, sorry, my principal question was if it was actually true. Thanks

Comment: Belongs to cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does. Tarjan's SCC algorithm works by performing a DFS on a graph and keeping track of the roots of the SCCs on a stack. One method of finding a topological sort is performing a DFS on a graph and keeping track of the exit order. The exit order of these nodes in Tarjan's SCC algorithm provide a topological sort.

Donald Knuth even mentions it [in an interview](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2213858&WT.mc_id=Author_Knuth_20Questions) when talking about Tarjan's SCC algorithm, which he says is one of his favorite:

> The data structures that he devised for this problem fit together in an amazingly beautiful way, so that the quantities you need to look at while exploring a directed graph are always magically at your fingertips. And his algorithm also does topological sorting as a byproduct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As Tarjan is based on Depth First Search all you have to do is to add the vertexes to the top of a list when each vertex reach the "closed" state.(ie. its dfs/tarjan call ends for that vertex)

Here is a C/C++/Pseudo-Code example:

```
void tarjan(int u) {
    visited[u] = true;
    closed[u] = false;
    //dfs + tarjan processing
    for (vi v = G[u].begin(); v != G[u].end(); v++) {
        if (!visited[*v]) {
            dfs(*v);
        } else if (!closed[*v]) {
            // has Cycle
        }
    }
    closed[u] = true;
    //add u to the top of your list here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it does, i've been using it and the same question came to my mind.

I actually haven't had time to demonstrate it but every test case (lot of thousands) always returns an topological sorted condensed graph.